# swift code convert speech to text using avspeechsynthizer

Tags: swift, speech-recognition

I have a app that is working fine using the swift avspeechsynthizer  which covers text to speech. Does the avspeechsynehtizer do the opposite speech to text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does! You have the `SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest` that you can use. Checkout [this](http://www.appcoda.com/siri-speech-framework/) tutorial for a detailed description of how to use this.

Comment: @alover I have only tried text to speech, but I assume it will work on the simulator though.